# how to writh full path of folder that is located locally in appData

Tags: javascript, json, appdata

JSON file:

```
{
  "url": ""
}
```

I want to insert to `url` the following path:

```
C:\Users\yw1kew\AppData\Local\dmv\dmv.data\cameraApp
```

I want it to be locally to any computer (not just my machine) therefore I need to start the path from `appdata` I think.

How to do that ?

This is not working:

```
{
  "url": "%AppData%\\dmv\\dmv.data\\cameraApp"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The path to `AppData\Local` is actually `LOCALAPPDATA` so your JSON object should be:

```
{
  "url": "%LOCALAPPDATA%\\dmv\\dmv.data\\cameraApp"
}
```

Comment: @TomCohen you need to tell us more than "not working". a specific error message or erroneous behaviour

Answer (score 0):

It should be %LOCALAPPDATA% 
See here https://www.microsoft.com/security/portal/mmpc/shared/variables.aspx